# Lock-Free way to Signal between Asyncs

Tags: .net, f#, lock-free

I am looking for a lock-free way to signal between two `Async`s in F#.  I have two  tail-recursive `async` functions, and I want one to yield until signaled by the other before proceeding to the next recursion.  I could use an event for this, but it looks like .NET events use locks internally.  The only solution I've found so far would be to use Keyed Events from ntdll.dll, but I would prefer a solution that does not require a direct reference to a platform-specific DLL.  Is there some way I can use `System.Threading.Interlocked` or another .NET technique to achieve this?

Here's a simple example of what I want to achieve:

```
let rec loop1 () =
    async {
        // do work
        // somehow signal loop2
        return! loop1 ()
    }

let rec loop2 state = 
    async {
        // wait for signal from loop1
        // do work
        return! loop2 state  // This would actually be a new state, not the old state
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered ManualResetEventSlim? It has better performance than the older ManualResetEvent, especially when wait times are short.

Comment: [Hopacs `IVar`](https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac/blob/master/Libs/Hopac.Core/Communication/IVar.cs) don't use locks, just CompareExchange which is lock free afaik.

Comment: @Szer Thanks, I looked at IVar, and posted a possible answer based on how that works.

Comment: Something to consider is that with Async which is an implementation of coroutines you don't want to block the thread or spin it. At the waiting point the Async should yield ie let the executing thread go and do other stuff. At some later point the signal is raised and some thread should pick up and execute the rest of the Async. For inspiration have a look at: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/async.fs#L1254 (note it uses locks internally)

Comment: @FuleSnabel, with the `LockFreeEvent` in the answer below, I can use `Async.AwaitEvent` to yield until the signal.  I think that uses only F# `Latch` (atomic compare-and-swap, no locks).

Comment: AFAICT `AwaitEvent` calls `AwaitAndBindResult_NoDirectCancelOrTimeout` which calls `AwaitResult_NoDirectCancelOrTimeout` which calls in some case `lock syncRoot`

Comment: Indeed, `ResultCell.AwaitResult_NoDirectCancelOrTimeout` has some mutable state that it's protecting with locks.  I guess I could write an alternative `AwaitEvent`... avoiding locks seems to require writing everything yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I took a look at Szer's suggestion to model the event on Hopac's IVar, and I examined how the standard F# Event is implemented.  Combining the two, I came up with this:

```
open System
open System.Threading

type LockFreeEvent<'args>() =
    let mutable multicast: Handler<'args> = null
    let wait = 
        let spin = SpinWait()
        spin.SpinOnce

    member __.Trigger arg = 
        match multicast with 
        | null -> ()
        | d -> d.Invoke(null, arg) |> ignore

    member __.Publish = 
        {new IEvent<'args> with
            member __.AddHandler handler = 
                let snapshot = multicast
                while snapshot <> Interlocked.CompareExchange<Handler<'args>>(&multicast, Delegate.Combine(multicast, handler) :?> Handler<'args>, snapshot) do
                    wait ()
            member __.RemoveHandler handler =
                let snapshot = multicast
                while snapshot <> Interlocked.CompareExchange(&multicast, Delegate.Remove(multicast, handler) :?> Handler<'args>, snapshot) do 
                    wait ()
            member this.Subscribe observer =
                let handler = new Handler<_>(fun sender args -> observer.OnNext(args))
                (this :?> IEvent<_,_>).AddHandler(handler)
                { new IDisposable with 
                    member __.Dispose() = (this :?> IEvent<_,_>).RemoveHandler(handler) 
                }
        }
```

How does this look?  I think this should implement the same functionality as a standard F# event, but without locking, unless there's locking going on in `Delegate.Combine`.  I think I might need to do `Trigger` differently as well.

Comment: Why not switch to Hopac? Async when I last used it wasn't really intended for CPU bound computing (where locks messes things up). Hopac is a better choice for that. Async is great for IO bound computing.

Comment: My actual use case involves a message queue (among other things).  One of the events on which I want to resume execution of my tail-recursive loop is a message being enqueued.  It's not necessarily a CPU-bound application.

Comment: If not CPU bound I wouldn't worry too much about locks or no locks especially since it seems it's hard to avoid that with Async (from reading the source). Another reason to avoid locks are priority inversion but on non-real-time OS:es this is usually not a big concern.

What about `MailboxProcessor`?

Comment: Actually, I'm laying some groundwork here for a larger project where I'd like to be able to create a `MailboxProcessor` that can optionally use an external persistent queue (e.g. RabbitMQ).  So, I want it to be able to wake up immediately when a message is enqueued in the persistent queue, but I also want it to be able to performant when enqueuing and dequeueing high volumes of messages from an in-memory queue.